# Why isn't SSMS honoring my default database settings?

Tags: ssms

For some reason SSMS isn't honoring my default database setting.  I have set my default database using

```
Exec sp_defaultdb @loginame='[username]', @defdb='[database_name]'
```

or by using Security > Logins > [my login] > Properties > Default Database

This seemed to have started when I took my default database offline and then couldn't log in.  I had to use sp_defaultdb to change to another database until I could bring it back online.  Now it just goes to master, even though it's set to my default db when I open my login's properties.  Any ideas?

I'm using SSMS 2008 & SQL Server 2008.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rookie mistake:  A few weeks ago I had set the 'Connect to database:' to the master db on the Login dialog (Connection Properties tab).

Comment: I had to disconnect and reconnect to make this property accessible